# Identifying what golfed code does?

Tags: discussion, new-genre, testing

I've got a bit of obfuscated javascript, and I'd like to find out what it does. I could read up on obfuscating in javascript, or I could ask some people who know their stuff.

Where would I post a question like this? It's not a code-golf question per se, but I think it's far more suited to find capable answerers on codegolf.stackexchange than on stackoverflow.

It was flagged as malware by a hoster which spiked my interest, so it might spike yours too. If anybody's interested, check revision history **at your own risk**.

Comment: maybe a popularity contest for the best de-obfuscated and commented version of the code?

Comment: I don't think it's very advisable to post malware without big warnings about not running it.

Comment: It's a JS/TrojanDownloader.Agent.NRL trojan: https://i.imgur.com/6epkJvy.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is really a good fit for any site on the StackExchange network. It definitely doesn't fit here. The two closest fits are probably StackOverflow and Security, but I don't think either of them would want it either.

(FWIW you really don't need to do much reading at all to decipher your particular question. [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is all you need for it to make sense).

Comment: Pretty much what I thought. For future reference & people being in the same situation, is there another site (-network) which will help with these kinds of questions?

Answer (score 1):

This question would be much better suited for Super User or Stack Overflow than for Code Golf.

Deobfuscating the code is trivial: Just replace `document.body.appendChild` with `return` and execute the function. (To be on the safe side, disconnect from the internet first.)

This shows that the code injects the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://URL-ELIDED-TO-AVOID-TRIGGERING-ANTIVIRUS/" defer="defer" id="Cbucwozzvh0t"></script>
```

The hostname doesn't resolve to an IP address, so – at least for now – the code won't be able to do any damage.

Comment: 'This question would be ... suited for ... Stack Overflow" -- I'm afraid not. It's not a specific programming question, it's not too useful and one might even claim it doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: @JanDvorak I've seen questions on StackOverflow before asking to explain some obfuscated code and they were well received.